# Why is the result cache always disabled in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, cache

I'm trying to enable the result cache in Oracle 11g. I have used Enterprise Manager to change the `result_cache_max_size` and `result_cache_max_result` values to '1M' and '100' respectively (maybe these aren't optimal settings, but I'm just trying to get it to work!).

After I make these changes I use the following query to see if the changes have really been made:

```
select * from V$PARAMETER where LOWER("NAME") like '%result_cache%';
```

I can see that both have been set correctly. However, when I run queries with the `result_cache` hint, I can see from the Autotrace that the cache isn't being used. If I then run the following query:

```
SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;
```

I can see that it's status is 'DISABLED'. Restarting the database just makes the `result_cache_max_size` parameter go back to 0 (disabled).

How can I enable the result cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Enterprise Edition? It looks like this is a EE feature:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm

CTRL + F the docs and search for result cache and supported editions.

Comment: I'm using standard edition, so this must be why it doesn't work...thanks for your answer!