# Result Cache disabled in Oracle 12c Enterprise - BYPASS status

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, cache

I have two database instances, development and production that are fairly identical.  On production, result cache is working fine, in development it is not.  The value for the database parameter `result_cache_max_size` was set to `0` so I reset it to remove the value, bounced the database, and when the database was back up, the value was still set to `0` so I tried starting with a `PFILE` with no value for `result_cache_max_size` and same problem.  Then I tried setting it to `20M` (value from production) and bounced, but same results. 
I then invoked

```
SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;
```

which returns `BYPASS`.

The parameters `result_cache_max_result` and `result_cache_mode` are set to `5` and `MANUAL` on both databases.

I am using Enterprise Edition on both instances (so question [Why is the result cache always disabled in Oracle 11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/108189/50938) does not apply to me):

Development:

```
SYS@extdev02> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
...
```

Production:

```
extuat01> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
...
```

Edit:  Tried `bypass` proc per @BalazsPapp answer but no luck.  I think I tried it already, but without the second parm, which would have defaulted to false per the documentation.  Today's try, including a `flush` proc just for fun:

```
SYS@extdev02> select dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual; 

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
---------------------------
BYPASS

SYS@extdev02> exec dbms_result_cache.bypass(true, false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SYS@extdev02> exec dbms_result_cache.flush

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SYS@extdev02> select dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
--------------------------
BYPASS

SYS@extdev02> exec dbms_result_cache.bypass(false, false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SYS@extdev02> select dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
--------------------------
BYPASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which returns `BYPASS`.

Then enable it:

```
SQL> SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLED

SQL> exec dbms_result_cache.bypass(true, false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BYPASS

SQL> exec dbms_result_cache.bypass(false, false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;

DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.STATUS()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLED

SQL>
```

[DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.BYPASS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.html#GUID-8B6B370A-148A-4916-9F7E-275DC4ED2A0B)

Comment: I thought I tried that yesterday, but tried it again today, with no change in status of `BYPASS`

Comment: @MarkStewart Ok, then we need the parameters from your spfile. Maybe you have set `shared_pool_size` to `0` and the database is unable to allocate enough memory for the result cache as described in **Result Cache Can Not Be Enabled (Doc ID 563828.1)**. I was able to reproduce this issue on 19.4 by setting `sga_target` to 512M and `shared_pool_size` to `0` in my spfile. If that is the case, then you just simply need to change the memory parameters. Like removing `shared_pool_size` or setting a minimal value for it. After I removed `shared_pool_size=0` from my spfile, result cache came back.

Comment: Perfect!  Checked `shared_pool_size` in prod; was `2240M`. Set `shared_pool_size` in dev to current size (`1280M`) and bounce db and it works.  Thanks for the MoS link.